# Expected value of maximum of two numbers, where one is normal distributed

Tags: optimization, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, expected-value, stochastic-integrals

I am searching something similar to the first order loss function ( $\mathbb{E}[max({y_{i}-y_{i},0})])$ (where $y_{i}$ is normally distributed) but for $\mathbb{E}[min(y_{i},d_{i})]$ , where $y_{i}$ is my number of products and $d_{i}$ the normally distributed random variable.
I need this to maximize my expected yield of product i, which is given by $\mathbb{E}[min(y_{i},d_{i})] \cdot e_{i}$, where $e_{i}$ is the revenue of product i.

Does anyone has an idea or literature recommendations to calculate/ approximate $\mathbb{E}[min(y_{i},d_{i})]$  ?

Kind regards, Alex :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y\sim N(0,1)$ and $d$ is a number. Then
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}[Y\wedge d]&=\mathsf{E}[(Y\wedge d) 1\{Y>d\}]+\mathsf{E}[(Y\wedge d)1\{Y\le d\}] \\
&=d\,\mathsf{P}(Y>d)+\mathsf{E}[Y1\{Y\le d\}] \\
&=d(1-\Phi(d))+\int_{-\infty}^dy\phi(y)\,dy \\
&=d(1-\Phi(d))-\phi(d),
\end{align}
where $\Phi(\cdot)$ and $\phi(\cdot)$ are the standard normal cdf and pdf.

Comment: If $Y  \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2})$, does the equation becomes to :
d(1- $\Phi (\frac{d-\mu}{\sigma}))-\phi(d)$, where $\phi(d)$ is the normal pdf with $\mu$ and $\sigma$?

Comment: @AlexKrause If $Y\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$, then
$$
\mathsf{E}[Y\wedge d]=\sigma\mathsf{E}[Y'\wedge d']+\mu,
$$
where $Y'\sim N(0,1)$ and $d'=(d-\mu)/\sigma$. Now, use the result for the $N(0,1)$ case.